# Binding key presses

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, raspberry-pi, key-bindings

I'm currently working on project where I ssh to a raspberry pi from my laptop to control some motors. I have written some code in Python that allows you to enter a letter and depending on the letter it moves forwards or backwards. However you have to press enter after every letter for the code to execute. 
Is there a way that the interface detects letters without the need to press enter. 
I know you can bind key presses in tkinter but I can not do that through ssh. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I could not find that as I did not fully know what I was looking for

Comment: Basically you can put the sys.stdin/terminal into "raw mode" and read 1 character at a time as shown in some of the answers there. the curses answered here is an option too, but then the whole terminal will be set to the curses mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) library for that.

You can grab the key that was pressed using the `screen.getch()` function. It will return the decimal code of the key (see [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

An example:

```
import curses


screen = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(1)

key = ''

while key != ord('q'):  # press <Q> to exit the program
    key = screen.getch()  # get the key
    screen.addch(0, 0, key)  # display it on the screen
    screen.refresh()

    # the same, but for <Up> and <Down> keys:
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        screen.addstr(0, 0, "Up")
    elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        screen.addstr(0, 0, "Down")

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Okay that's the kinda thing I need, thanks. If I wanted to print out what was entered do you just do print(key). I'm not sure what the actual input is

Comment: @JoranBeasley although I am running it from a raspberry pi I don't use Linux coding. I just run some Python script.

Comment: that is python ... but that code only works on linux (ie raspberrry pi)

Comment: Okay thanks that is clear now. I will implement this in my code. And it should work. :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley okay. I hadn't seen those terms within Python before so assumed they were bash or something else. Cheers though

Comment: Does this only work in Python 2.7 I'm running 3. Something and apparently the is not attributes of the module. ie it can not find curses.initscr or cbreak or any others

Comment: @user3811719 It should certainly work on Python 3... https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Using curses might be an overkill as it is mainly used for drawing full screen cli applications. See my answer for just bind events to keypresses

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [sshkeyboard](https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. Simply `pip install sshkeyboard`, and then use the following code to detect key presses over SSH:

```py
from sshkeyboard import listen_keyboard

def press(key):
    print(f"'{key}' pressed")

def release(key):
    print(f"'{key}' released")

listen_keyboard(
    on_press=press,
    on_release=release,
)
```

Inside `def press` you could have some logic to react to specific keys:

```py
def press(key):
    if key == "up":
        print("up pressed")
    elif key == "down":
        print("down pressed")
    elif key == "left":
        print("left pressed")
    elif key == "right":
        print("right pressed")
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, since the above school project, I have gone to uni and graduated. whilst not trying your method, I prefer it as it looks more readable to me.

Comment: @george congrats on the graduation!

Comment: Congrats! Then this is a good future reference for others who will face the same issue